# What is $ObjectType.Account.Fields.Financial_Discovery__c.Createable?

Tags: visualforce, fields

I am confused by this syntax:

```
$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Financial_Discovery__c.Createable
```

on the page I can kinda tell what it does but I want to know what specifically this refers to. Is this accessing Field level security ? If so how do I know what the last word actually means ? Because there is also:

```
$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Client_Segmentation__c.Accessible
```

which is not a type of field permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it refers to the field's describe results, including field level permissions for the context user. Accessible is analogous to Visible, Createable means it can be set upon new record creation, Updateable means it can be modified after record creation. Field level security does not tell the whole story. For example, if a field is a master-detail field without the reparentable option, then Createable would be true, but Updateable would be false. You can access most of the attributes mentioned in [DescribeSobjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) under the Field section.

Answer (score 2):

You can see some detail on each of the properties by looking at the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe) Apex API documentation. Looks like the [Java bean](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm) pattern applies where `is` or `get` can be dropped. So for accessible:

> **isAccessible()**
> Returns true if the current user can see this object,
>   false otherwise.